# R Plot Bars are disappearing in grid.arrange/plot_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, gridextra, cowplot

I have a problem with bars from my plots disappearing when I combine multiple plots.

Here is the code I´m using:

````
station<-c("Eins", "Zwei", "Drei","Vier")
x1<-c(200, 185, 165,180)
x2<-c(185,150,148,25)
x3<-c(156,125,141,36)

test.data<-data.frame(station,x1,x2,x3)


plot_sof<-ggplot(test.data, aes(x=station, y=x1))
plot_sof + geom_bar(stat="identity",na.rm=TRUE)

plot_sof_1<-ggplot(test.data, aes(x=station, y=x2))
plot_sof_1+geom_bar(stat = "identity",na.rm=TRUE)

plot_sof_2<-ggplot(test.data, aes(x=station, y=x3))
plot_sof_2+geom_bar(stat = "identity",na.rm=TRUE)

plot_grid(plot_sof, plot_sof_1, plot_sof_2, labels=c("x1", "x2", "x3"))

grid.arrange(plot_sof, plot_sof_1, plot_sof_2, ncol=1)```
````

[image: Example of one of the plots which should combined]

[image: First try to combine the plots via grid.arrange, the bars are missing]

[image: Second try via plot_grid, here are the bars also missing]

Does anyone know why the bars are missing and maybe know a solution or a workaround for that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this, you have to assign the new geom to your objects:

```
#Code
plot_sof<-ggplot(test.data, aes(x=station, y=x1))
plot_sof <-plot_sof + geom_bar(stat="identity",na.rm=TRUE)

plot_sof_1<-ggplot(test.data, aes(x=station, y=x2))
plot_sof_1 <- plot_sof_1+geom_bar(stat = "identity",na.rm=TRUE)

plot_sof_2<-ggplot(test.data, aes(x=station, y=x3))
plot_sof_2 <- plot_sof_2+geom_bar(stat = "identity",na.rm=TRUE)

plot_grid(plot_sof, plot_sof_1, plot_sof_2, labels=c("x1", "x2", "x3"))

grid.arrange(plot_sof, plot_sof_1, plot_sof_2, ncol=1)
```

Outputs:

[image]

[image]

Comment: well thanks, thats the solution. It´s so obvious that i´m sorry if i wasted your time with this stupid question.

Comment: @André_1090 It is a pleasure helping you, moreover the learning curve of `ggplot2` has this kind of things but they help you to be a better coder :)